# image slideshow with pause in between animation

Tags: jquery, queue

We have tried to mimic the pause effect for image slideshow by using fxqueue js.

but fxqueue js only supports jquery 1.3.2.

we able to manage pause behavior within that jquery version.but it is not working for current jquery version.

http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/fxqueues

is there any other method/plugin to  mimic the pause behavior and continue that animation  from that point after play button.

**Update : please check jsfiddle below. it is working for hardcoded ids. but we need to work the queue for dynamic ids.**

jsfiddle.net/4wSmP/3/

Comment: you need something like `$(element).animate({left: 100}).delay(100).animate({left: 0});` ?

Comment: but in general case, you can write something like fxqueue within 10-30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try effect `callback` function if it suits your requirements.

When effect finishes it calls `callback` (*where you can put a delay*) and chain effects this way.

For example:

> **[.show( duration [, callback] )](http://api.jquery.com/show/)**
>
> durationA string or number determining how long the animation will run.
>
> callbackA function to call once the animation is complete.